# JavaScript night mode buttons with cookies

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I updated a JavaScript file for my website. I added in use of cookies. Bear in mind that I only just started to learn about cookies and it had errors. So I moved code around to stop it from having errors. However, I'm not sure if this is efficient.

Sometimes when I refresh my page it will show up with no styling for a split second. Even though it is only minute I would like to see if I can rid this problem. Is it efficient?

```js
document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoad);

function handleDocumentLoad() {

    checkCookie();

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var nightmode = getCookie("lights");
        if (nightmode == "off") {
            lightsOff();
        } else {
            lightsOn();
        }
    }

    //Variables
    var offSwitch;
    var onSwitch;
    var style;

    //Functions
    function lightsOff() { /*This changes the background colour to black and makes text white*/

        offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOff
        onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOn
        style = document.getElementById("pageStyle"); //Targets stylsheet

        onSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOn); //When clicked this action is performed

        document.cookie = "lights = off;  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";

        style.setAttribute('href', 'css/darkStyle.css');
        onSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn Off Night Mode";
        onSwitch.style.display = "inline";
        offSwitch.style.display = "none";
    }

    function lightsOn() { /*This changes the background colour to a white and makes text black*/

        offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOff
        onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOn
        style = document.getElementById("pageStyle"); //Targets stylsheet

        offSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOff); //When clicked this action is performed

        document.cookie = "lights = on;  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";

        style.setAttribute('href', 'css/lightStyle.css');
        offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";
        onSwitch.style.display = "none";
        offSwitch.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8"

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/*Layout for phones and tablets e.g. iPhone 5 and iPad*/

    /*webpage fades in*/
    html {
        animation: fadein 2s;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    /*animation*/
    @keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to { opacity: 1; }
    }

    /*main colour settings for page*/
    body {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin: 0 0 100px;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    /*List in nav*/
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    /*Navigation*/
    nav {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        border: solid 1px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    ol {
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 6em;
    }

    /*Links*/
    a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*Main heading*/
    h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left: -2.5em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*Secondary heading*/
    h2 {
        font-size: 2.75em;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    /*Tertiary heading*/
    h3 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    /*Text*/
    p {
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    /*Images*/
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        border: solid 0px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }

    textarea {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid 1px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 2px;
        resize: none;
    }

    input {
        border: solid 1px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #logo {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        max-height: 100px;
        max-width: 100px;
        border: 0px;
    }

    #enter {
        margin-top: 5em;
        margin-bottom: 5em;
        margin-left: 3em;
        max-width: 90%;
        max-height: 90%;
    }

    video {
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }

    /*Footer*/
    footer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*Main Body*/
    #mainContent {
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid 1px #1C1C1C;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #mainContent img {
        display: inline;
        max-width: 375px;
        max-height: 375px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 2em;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }

    /*Light Switches*/
    #lightSwitchOff, #lightSwitchOn {
        display: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }


/*Layout for device with a min-width of 1024px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

    p, li {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2.75em;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 2.25em;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    #enter {
        max-width: 60%;
        max-height: 60%;
    }

    #lightSwitchOff, #lightSwitchOn {
        display: inline;
    }
}

/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1280px (720p HD)*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

    li {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 2.25em;
    }

    #enter {
        max-width: 40%;
        max-height: 40%;
    }
}

/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1920px (1080p HD)*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {

    p {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }

    #enter {
        max-width: 40%;
        max-height: 40%;
    }
}

/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 200px e.g. iMac*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 2000px) {

    p {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <title>Ryan Simms</title>

    <!-- ****** faviconit.com favicons ****** -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <!-- ****** faviconit.com favicons ****** -->

    <link id ="pageStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightStyle.css" type="text/css"> <!-- Loads Default Stylesheet -->

    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'); <!-- Custom Font -->
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <script src="scripts/lightSwitch-contact.js"></script> <!-- Loads LightSwitch Script -->

    <ol>
    <a href="cover-letter-and-cv"><img alt="Enter" id="enter" title="Click to Enter" src="images/logo.jpg"></img></a>
    </ol>

    <footer>
      Website Created by Ryan Simms <br>
      <button type="button" id="lightSwitchOff"></button>
      <button type="button" id="lightSwitchOn"></button>
    </footer> <!-- Closes Footer -->

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your page is initially loading without styles is because you programmed it to wait for he DOM to load before loading the styles :P

```
document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoad);
```

Your functions are small but, really, there's too much happening in them. Your function should only have to change the stylesheet. This type of stuff should be done in the stylesheet itself rather than with js:

- `onSwitch.style.display = "inline";` Remove theses lines of JS that are hiding and showing the buttons and do it with CSS in the appropriate stylesheet instead. eg, the lightsOff stylesheet should hide the lightsOff button and show the lightsOn button and the lightsOn stylesheet should do the opposite.
- Don't use JS to change the innerHTML every time the function is run because that requires the DOM to be loaded, which slows everything down. This can be done in the HTML and doesn't need to be changed with JS `offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";` Just put the text in the button and leave it alone: `<button type="button" id="lightSwitchOff">Turn On Night Mode</button>`

Once you make these changes your JS only needs a single element from the DOM: the stylesheet. As long as you put the script immediately below the stylesheet you don't need to wait for the DOM to load.

#### Here's the re-write:

```
function handleDocumentLoad() {
  var style = document.getElementById("pageStyle")

  checkCookie();

  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return ""; 
  }

  function checkCookie() {
    var nightmode = getCookie("lights");
    if (nightmode == "off") {
      lightsOff();
    } else {
      lightsOn();
    }
  }

  function lightsOff() {
    document.cookie = "lights = off;  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
    style.setAttribute('href', 'darkStyle.css');
  }

  function lightsOn() {
    document.cookie = "lights = on;  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
    style.setAttribute('href', 'lightStyle.css');
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff").addEventListener("click", lightsOn);
    document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn").addEventListener("click", lightsOff);
  });

}

handleDocumentLoad();
```

**Change your HTML to:**

```
<button type="button" id="lightSwitchOff">Turn Off Night Mode</button>
<button type="button" id="lightSwitchOn">Turn On Night Mode</button>
```

**Add these lines to `lightStyle.css`**

```
#lightSwitchOff{ display:inline; }
#lightSwitchOn{ display:none; }
```

**Add these lines to `darkStyle.css`**

```
#lightSwitchOff{ display:none; }
#lightSwitchOn{ display:inline; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, the reason why I use the DOMContentLoaded is because I was taught that way in university (college). I'm still learning about website design more and more as I am more of a video games programmer.

I knew I was repeating myself on certain lines of code but I wasn't so sure what else would work. I just got it to work and then would deal with the little annoying parts after. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh actually the code you gave doesn't work.

Comment: @Ryan - Can you make a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) duplicating the problem? It was intended as general advice, not code that you should copy/paste, but if you can duplicate the problem for me I'll be happy to update my answer.

Comment: I made a Plunkr using your code, I striped the HTML down to the basics so it's just the button for now: https://embed.plnkr.co/sndjHszYLo7QOX55Fj66/

Comment: @Ryan - Sorry about that, the problem was 1) The `style` variable needed to be defined before calling the function that needed it, and 2) I had the event handlers switched. I've updated the answer, and the fixed plunkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nCpg3xyNqoKARzP8shOb?p=preview).

Comment: I noticed that even after using your updated code I still get the same problem, if you go onto my website https://ryan-simms.com/ and refresh the page when night mode is turned on change page it shows up with no css for a split second sometimes, it's like a flash of light.

Comment: @Ryan: you didn't take my advice about putting the script directly below your `<link>`. on your website the script is below the `@import` call, which is going to slow down your page. import is synchronous and [should be avoided](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/), but either way, you need to move that script tag up so it is directly below the `<link>` tag, like i did it in the plunkr.

Comment: I just checked the HTML code on plunker and there isn't any difference.

Comment: @Ryan - Fine. I forgot to change it in the plunkr. My bad. Do as I say, not as I do. [Here's the updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KPDjfpYfpdUFagzylbks?p=preview) with the `@import` converted to a link tag and the `<script>` tag placed properly.

Comment: I didn't realise what you meant so I was wondering, after using your updated plunker it still flashes up with no css for a split second before loading with the lights off.

Comment: @Ryan - I don't see what you're talking about, it works perfectly for me. If you're on a slow connection there's nothing you can do about it, it will take your stylesheet a second to load. The only way to get around that is to load the stylesheet inline. - Anyway, this is getting to the point of being off-topic for code-review. I'm now helping you debug something that's not working rather than reviewing something that is working. If you want advice on how to load the stylesheet inline I would suggest asking on stackoverflow. good luck and godspeed.

Comment: The code was working in the first place, I was told to come to this site from stack overflow to improve it. I've tried the site on many different connections. On my end when I am on my site, I refresh the page or click another page when nightmode is on it flashes white for like half a second with no css before loading the dark css

Comment: @Ryan - The point is that we're not free code-writers. You're obviously expecting someone to re-write your code for you and that's not what Stackexchange is about. I've told you why you're getting that flash on a slower connection - if the style sheet is not cached it will take a second to load. You can come up with your own solution to that problem. Here's one last example, and this one sucks, but it solves the problem of having to wait for the stylesheet. Get creative and come up with your own solution. [Here's my last plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9HbCx7vUBG7OotgwMU1z?p=preview).

Comment: Hey, sorry if I made you mad or anything. I never intended to do so, your help has been really appreciated and it really helped me learn more about JavaScript. I think I have found a solution and it seems to be working for me now.

Comment: Glad I could be of at least *some* help. And I apologize if I gave you the impression that I was mad.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [the advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/182680/120114) from [I wrestled a bear once](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39953/i-wrestled-a-bear-once) - especially about the DOM queries each time the function is run. If you did need to alter DOM elements when a function is run, it is best to store a reference to any such DOM elements in a variable when the DOM is ready and use that variable whenever the function is run.

In your original code, these three lines appear to exist in both functions (i.e. `lightsOff()` and `lightsOn()`). If you were to keep those variables, those assignment lines can be moved out to the `handleDocumentLoad()` function, since they are the same in both functions. This fits the **[*Don't Repeat Yourself*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)**
 (i.e. D.R.Y.) principle.

```
offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOff
onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOn
style = document.getElementById("pageStyle"); //Targets stylsheet
```

For more tips like this, check out [this article about optimizing Javascript](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/). I know it is a few years old but still quite relevant (for now).

Comment: +1 for the article... the quotes are great.. and where's my hats invitation?? i'm jelly.

Comment: Thanks - [_come check out Winter Bash_!](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/)